# how to upload video to azure media services from aws s3

Tags: java, azure, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, azure-media-services

I would like to know how we can upload the video files to azure media services from aws s3 buckets using the API (JAVA). I have checked the documentations and samples everywhere and couldn't find any reference on how to upload the video from s3 to the media services.

I was able to upload to the azure storage. But i want to upload to the media services to create streaming urls.

Comment: Is aws bucket can give a fileStream?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't have any method to directly transfer the data between `S3` and `Azure`, We can get the `InputStream` from `Amazon S3` and write them to `Azure` storage.

To get `InputStream` from `S3`, use this

```
AWSCredentials awsCredentials = awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
AmazonS3Client amazonS3 = new AmazonS3Client(awsCredentials);
InputStream is = amazonS3.getObject(bucket, filePath).getObjectContent();
```

Comment: I tried this method and its taking long time to transfer the video file from s3 to the azure. Are there any ways to directly transfer the video from s3 to azure?

Comment: No we can't. In S3 there is a option called `MultiPart Uploading` to upload the documents part by part. So, Can you please check with the documents of Azure that is there any similar concepts like `MultiPart Uploading` and start using it. I have searched for it please see [this](http://justazure.com/azure-blob-storage-part-4-uploading-large-blobs/)

Comment: Yes, it did help. But the transfer speed is very low because it reads all the data and then only sending back to azure.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't help as its for the storage and not for the media services. Media services does not have that method.